# Bindgen skipping definitions from C++ header file

Tags: rust, bindgen

I am trying to compile bindings for the [SEAL C++ library](https://github.com/Microsoft/SEAL). Here is [my repo](https://github.com/Belval/seal-rs).

```
// Generate the bindings
let bindings = bindgen::Builder::default()
    .generate_inline_functions(true)
    .derive_default(true)
    .header("./seal/src/seal/seal.h")
    .clang_arg("-I./seal/src/")
    .clang_arg("-std=c++17")
    .clang_arg("-x")
    .clang_arg("c++")
    .opaque_type("std::.*")
    .whitelist_type("seal::.*")
    .generate()
    .expect("Unable to generate bindings");

let out_path = PathBuf::from("./src/");
bindings
    .write_to_file(out_path.join("bindings.rs"))
    .expect("Couldn't write bindings!");
```

bindings.rs does not have anything from [defaultparams.h](https://github.com/Microsoft/SEAL/blob/aa7bf57aa11a91d9ca8712816550ae68793add99/src/seal/defaultparams.h)

What do I have to add to the Builder object to include [defaultparams.h](https://github.com/Microsoft/SEAL/blob/aa7bf57aa11a91d9ca8712816550ae68793add99/src/seal/defaultparams.h)'s functions in the generated bindings? I need `coeff_modulus_128()` for example.

I tried whitelisting the `std::vector` but it did not have any impact on the generated bindings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by adding `.whitelist_function("seal::.*")` to the `build.rs` file. Since the inline functions weren't enclosed in a type, they were not whitelisted by the current config.

Comment: Hint: You can mark your own answer as the solution to your problem by clicking on the green check mark ✓

Comment: Still have 6 hours to go until I can :)

Comment: Oh, didn't realize there was a time limit, thanks for the info :)